# IE9 + jwplayer: __flash__addCallback error if move player in dom before calling player.load()

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, media-player, jwplayer

UPDATE:
The premise of this question turned out to be misguided.  The problem does not happen unless the move is in response to a user-click.  Please see [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/28999/ie9-move-and-load-player-in-response-to-user-click-load-fails/).

---

I have been knocking my head against a bug for a few days and am hoping someone can help.

I have a jquery script that makes calls to a jwplayer object ("myplayer") using the [jwplayer javascript api](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference).  For example, to load myplayer with a particular video, I call:

```
myplayer.load('my_url');
```

This works fine in both firefox and internet explorer, so long as I don't first move the player to a different location in the DOM.

However, my script sometimes moves the player from location A to location B and then back to location A, before calling  `myplayer.load()`.  This works fine in firefox.  But in internet explorer 9, I get an error on this line:

```
return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
```

which is inside this function:

```
function __flash__addCallback(instance, name) {
  instance[name] = function () { 
    return eval(instance.CallFunction("<invoke name=\""+name+"\" returntype=\"javascript\">" + __flash__argumentsToXML(arguments,0) + "</invoke>"));
  }
}
```

If I trace what is happening in the internet explorer debugger, I see that `myplayer.load('my_url')` calls `this.callInternal("jwLoad",u)` in `jwplayer.js`, and it is apparently while executing `this.callInternal("jwLoad",u)` that the error occurs.

**Details:**

The html looks something like this:

```
<div id='stage'>
    <div id='myplayer_wrapper'>
        <object id='myplayer'>...</object>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='holding-pen'></div>
```

When the player is not being used, I move its wrapper-div to the holding-pen:

```
var el = $('#myplayer_wrapper');            
$('#holding-pen').append(el);
```

After moving the player's wrapper-div to the holding-pen, the html now looks like:

```
<div id='stage'></div>
<div id='holding-pen'>
    <div id='myplayer_wrapper'>
        <object id='myplayer'>...</object>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I wish to use the player, I move its wrapper-div back to the stage-div:

```
var el = $('#myplayer_wrapper');            
$('#stage).append(el);
```

After moving the player's wrapper-div to the stage-div, the html looks the same as it did originally:

```
<div id='stage'>
    <div id='myplayer_wrapper'>
        <object id='myplayer'>...</object>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='holding-pen'></div>
```

On page load, I create the player-object and move it to the holding-pen.  I then move it to the stage and load a video.

If the user clicks on, for example, an image-thumbnail, I move the video-player to the holding-pen and move the selected image to the stage.

If the user then clicks on a video-thumbnail, I retrieve the video-player from the holding pen and move it back to the stage.  I then load the player with the selected video. This is where the "_*flash*_addCallback" problem occurs in internet explorer.

Does anyone have any insight into what may be going on?  Or any suggestions for how I can get this to work in internet explorer?

Thank you very much!

Comment: might be related : https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/530

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?  Also the Updated link at the top of the question is unavailable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823994/ie9-move-and-load-flash-player-in-response-to-user-click-load-fails ..... this link was not working , I have changed it with this .... http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports/28999/ie9-move-and-load-player-in-response-to-user-click-load-fails/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known problem with IE (6, 7, 8 & 9) as far as various posts on the web go. It depends on the combination of `Flash` versions and `IE` versions.

`IE` has, seemingly, reserved methods for the words one would expect from media players:

- play
- stop
- pause
- length

...and the `__flash__addCallback()` function seem to use those same words. `play` and `stop` are a vital part of `Flash` movies and dictate when they play or stop. I can't confirm if later versions of `Flash` have amended this.

Sources supporting this:

- [Problem occurring in __flash__addCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786325/problem-occurring-in-flash-addcallback)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glow-users/7A0tOf60Sl4
- [ExternalInterface.addCallback not working in IE8 Flash 10.0 or below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249351/externalinterface-addcallback-not-working-in-ie8-flash-10-0-or-below)

An interesting twist:
http://beweb.pbworks.com/w/page/53110280/Flash%20IE8%20Javascript%20Error

Some people have recommended using [**SWFObject**](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to go around browser problems such as this one, others have looked at the way Soundcloud fixed their player - though [this SoundCloud article](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1331463-why-is-my-widget-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer-) shatters any shred of hope there.

In the end of the day, the problem lies on how `Flash` expects `JavaScript` to communicate with itself, which crashes with reserved methods in `IE`. You may have to:

- update your **jwplayer**
- create an issue on **jwplayer**'s bug tracker
- make a workaround to the problem yourself...

Something that has helped me go around many IE problems is changing the DOCTYPE to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Simple and yet effective. Note that `IE7` prefers that the word DOCTYPE is written *uppercase*. Whenever I try this I know I've turned into a desperate zombIE. :P

And last but not the least, make sure you close the last single quote below:

```
$('#stage).append(el);
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same message with [this website](http://www.mediatheque-numerique.com/), hence the bounty. The problem occurs when you play the first video, then go to the next one using the thumbnails on the left, then play the second video.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: +1, it looks useful. I'm going to try to install a VM so that I can test this.

Comment: @greg0ire try the images from http://modern.ie/, they are the best ones. ;) Yes, VM images can be ridiculously big... Last I checked all images from IE7-10 amounted to over 18GB.

Comment: I use [ievms](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms), which takes it source from moder.ie, but I lack disk space... it will wait until monday I guess.

Comment: I updated flowplayer, and now it works like a charm. Here, have 400 rep for your hard work.